# Manipulate and parameters in NDSolve

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, manipulate

I'm trying to use Manipulate to change some parameters in these differential equations, as follows:

```
 sol[\[Alpha]_, \[Beta]_] := 
  sol[\[Alpha], \[Beta]] = 
   NDSolve[{D[S[t], t] + \[Alpha]*S[t]*Inf[t] == 0, 
     D[Inf[t], t] + \[Beta]*Inf[t] - \[Alpha]*S[t]*Inf[t] == 0, 
     D[R[t], t] - \[Beta]*Inf[t] == 0, S[0] == 0.88, Inf[0] == 0.11, 
     R[0] == 0}, {S[t], Inf[t], R[t]}, {t, 0, 60}];


Manipulate[
 Plot[{S[t] /. sol[\[Alpha], \[Beta]], R[t] /. sol[\[Alpha], \[Beta]],
    Inf[t] /. sol[\[Alpha], \[Beta]]}, {t, 0, 40}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"Sanos", "Recuperados", "Infectados"}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, Green, Red}, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
  GridLines -> Automatic, AxesLabel -> {"Días", "Población"}, 
  AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, 12]], {\[Alpha], 0.1, 0.9}, {\[Beta], 
  0.1, 0.9}]
```

But I get the following errors:
 ReplaceAll::reps: {NDSolve[{!(*SubscriptBox[([PartialD]), (0)](S[0]))+0.1 Inf[0] S[0]==0,!(*SubscriptBox[([PartialD]), (0)](Inf[0]))+0.1 Inf[0]-0.1 Inf[0] S[0]==0,!(*SubscriptBox[([PartialD]), (0)](R[0]))-0.1 Inf[0]==0,S[0]==0.88,Inf[0]==0.11,R[0]==0},{S[0],Inf[0],R[0]},{0,0,60}]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing.

```
General::ivar: 0.` is not a valid variable.

General::ivar: 0.` is not a valid variable.

General::ivar: 0.` is not a valid variable.

General::stop: Further output of General::ivar will be suppressed during this calculation.

NDSolve::dsvar: 0.` cannot be used as a variable.

ReplaceAll::reps: {NDSolve[<<1>>]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing.

ReplaceAll::reps: {NDSolve[{\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(0\)]\(S[0]\)\)+0.1 Inf[0] S[0]==0,\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(0\)]\(Inf[0]\)\)+0.1 Inf[0]-0.1 Inf[0] S[0]==0,\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(0\)]\(R[0]\)\)-0.1 Inf[0]==0,S[0]==0.88,Inf[0]==0.11,R[0]==0},{S[0],Inf[0],R[0]},{0,0,60}]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing.

General::stop: Further output of ReplaceAll::reps will be suppressed during this calculation.

NDSolve::dsvar: 0.` cannot be used as a variable.

NDSolve::dsvar: 0.` cannot be used as a variable.
```

General::stop: Further output of NDSolve::dsvar will be suppressed during this calculation.

Answer (score 2):

another option

```
Manipulate[

 Module[{t, S, Inf, R},
    {S, Inf, R} = NDSolveValue[{
       D[S[t], t] + α*S[t]*Inf[t] == 0,
       D[Inf[t], t] + β*Inf[t] - α*S[t]*Inf[t] == 0,
       D[R[t], t] - β*Inf[t] == 0,
       S[0]   == 0.88,
       Inf[0] == 0.11,
       R[0]   == 0},
      {S, Inf, R},{t, 0, 60}];

   Plot[{S[t], Inf[t], R[t]}, {t, 0, 40},
     PlotLegends -> {"Sanos", "Recuperados", "Infectados"},
     PlotStyle -> {Blue, Green, Red},
     PlotStyle -> Thick,
     GridLines -> Automatic,
     AxesLabel -> {"Días", "Población"},
     AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, 12]
     ]
  ],

 {α, 0.1, 0.9},
 {β, 0.1, 0.9},

 TrackedSymbols :> {α, β}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Great! it works perfectly. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Manipulate[
  sol[a_,b_]:={S[t],Inf[t],R[t]}/.NDSolve[{D[S[t],t]+a*S[t]*Inf[t]==0,
    D[Inf[t],t]+b*Inf[t]-a*S[t]*Inf[t]==0,D[R[t],t]-b*Inf[t]==0,S[0]==0.88,
    Inf[0]==0.11,R[0]==0},{S[t],Inf[t],R[t]},{t,0,60}][[1]];
  s=sol[a,b];Plot[s,{t,0,60}],{a,0.1,0.9},{b,0.1,0.9}]
```

and then undo each of those changes from your original code, one at a time, and see how many of those break things. Then try to study the documentation to try to understand why.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ParametricNDSolveValue`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolveValue.html) to create a parametric function and use it inside `Manipulate`:

```
ClearAll[pndsv]

pndsv = ParametricNDSolveValue[{D[S[t], t] + α*S[t]*Inf[t] == 0, 
    D[Inf[t], t] + β*Inf[t] - α*S[t]*Inf[t] == 0, 
    D[R[t], t] - β*Inf[t] == 0, 
    S[0] == 0.88, Inf[0] == 0.11,  R[0] == 0}, 
  {S, Inf, R}, {t, 0, 60}, {α, β}];

Manipulate[Plot[Evaluate @ Through @ pndsv[α, β] @ t, {t, 0, 40}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"Sanos", "Recuperados", "Infectados"}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, Green, Red}, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
  GridLines -> Automatic, AxesLabel -> {"Días", "Población"}, 
  AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, 12]], 
{α, 0.1, 0.9}, {β, 0.1, 0.9}]
```

[image]